# Can I both update and retrieve an element in a Map without two index calls?

Tags: go, hashmap

I have a map with integer values. I want to update a value and then check if the updated value exceeds a threshold.

If I didn't need to check the new value, then I would simply do

```
map[key] += 1
```

The obvious change if I want to check the new value would be:

```
old_val := map[key]
new_val := old_val + 1
map[key] = new_val
if (new_val > threshold) {
    return
}
```

However, this makes two index calls to the map, which is not necessarily a constant time operation.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
val_p := &(map[key])
*(val_p) += 1
if (*(val_p) > threshold) {
    return
}
```

However, GoLang maps are not addressable by design because the addresses can obviously change (although it wouldn't change in this case because I'm not altering the map).

Is there some function I could use to update the element in a map which returns the new value? Specifically for integers?

Comment: No, there is not. Have you measured a performance problem and profiled to narrow it down to the cost of the second map lookup, or is this purely speculative optimization?

Comment: No, it's just speculative, and I doubt there's a significant performance impact. It is a little bit annoying that it's something that's prevented by design which does have a tangible (though likely small) performance impact.

Comment: It's good that such magical/overloaded things are prevented by design, IMO. It makes the code much clearer to read.

Comment: Unless you've measured and profiled a performance problem, you can't really claim it has a tangible impact. You're guessing that it might. Trying to fix a problem you don't know you actually have is usually counterproductive.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to pass a function to a map along with a key and then have it update and return the associated value. It's definitely something that should be possible.

Comment: pass a function to a map? I don't even know what that means. But I'm pretty sure I'm very glad it's not possible.

Comment: If you just mixed up your words, and you mean it would be nice to pass a map to a function, which would update and return simultaneously... you can easily write a function to do that. I'm glad it's not part of the language, though. Single responsibility principle FTW.

Comment: I didn't mix up my words, you could do it with function pointers which are supported in go. You can pass a function as an argument to another function. I guess the syntax would look something like update(map, key, my_function) and it would check that my_function takes 1 input of the map's value type.

Comment: Okay, well then your words just don't make sense, because "pass a function to a map" doesn't make sense. You pass things to functions, not to maps. Your example looks like "pass a map and a function to a function"

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with "simple" values for the reasons you mentioned in the question.

What you may do is store a wrapper or a pointer in the map, and so you only need to lookup the value, and you only need to do it once; changing the data is changing the pointed value which is outside of the map, so you don't have to reassign (the pointer doesn't change).

For example:

```
const threshold = 3

m := map[string]*int{
    "one": new(int),
}

for {
    p := m["one"]
    fmt.Println("data=", *p)
    *p++
    if *p > threshold {
        fmt.Println("threshold reached", *p)
        break
    }
}
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZPg25KLblXe)):

```
data= 0
data= 1
data= 2
data= 3
threshold reached 4
```

Although note that this may not be faster due to pointer indirections. Measure if this is a critical part of your app.

Comment: And the garbage collector (GC) will have to follow all those pointers.